# RadioGroup is not saving preferences

Tags: android, eclipse, sharedpreferences, radio-group

I have following code:

This is in onCreate - I am trying to set default value of a radio button here, which will be the pre selected value on radio button.

```
pref = getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREF_SETTINGS, 0);                            

        RadioGroup rg_numberOfQuestions = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroupQuestions);
        int selectedOption = rg_numberOfQuestions.getCheckedRadioButtonId();    
        rb_NumberOfQuestions = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedOption);      
        rg_numberOfQuestions.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);      

        final RadioGroup rg_numbersBetween = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroupNumbersBetween);
        selectedOption = rg_numbersBetween.getCheckedRadioButtonId();   
        rb_NumbersBetween = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedOption);
        rg_numbersBetween.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

@Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup rg, int i) {                        
        switch (rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId())
        {
        case R.id.rb_0to10:
            savePref("rb_0to10", rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId());         
            break;

        case R.id.rb_0to25:
            savePref("rb_0to25", rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId());     
            break;

        case R.id.rb_0to50:
            savePref("rb_0to50", rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
            break;
        case R.id.rb_15:
            savePref("rb_15", rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
            break;

        case R.id.rb_25:
            savePref("rb_25", rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
            break;

        case R.id.rb_50:
            savePref("rb_50", rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
            break;          
        }       
    }   


private void savePref(String key, int value) {
        pref = getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREF_SETTINGS, 0);
        editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putInt(key, value);      
        editor.commit();
    }
```

Above code works first time it gets the default value of first radio button. But no matter what other radio button i select it is not working it is not saving the button click value it just gets first radio button always.

Comment: y dont u give name to ur pref rather than getting Constants.PREF_SETTINGS

Comment: @MT8 - I have given it a name it goes to Constants class and gets the string name

Comment: ok did u see in ddms that new value is storing or not?

Comment: @MT8 - Sorry new to android development. Where should i look under ddms to see the values? Also should i run in debug mode to look at those values? Or i can just see them?

Comment: Try removing before adding it into pref by editor.remove(key);

Comment: @SweetWisher - I added - editor.remove(key); before editor.putInt statement but that did not fix it.

Comment: Debug n see . You will get the missing point

Comment: @SweetWisher - I tried that many times. It gets the value when clicked on radio button and changes it. But when i go back and come back in settings. It again gets the old radiobutton value.

Comment: Where is the code to set radio button's default values which was previously selected??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41238/discussion-between-sweetwisher-and-noviceme)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can see the value itself in DDMS :
>
> Here is the image for Debugging and see the values in Shared Pref :

[image]

And

[image]

> you can pull and push files also in any location... To see Values in
>   Shared pref click that file
>
> on Top right side there is 2 icon of mobile with pink Arrow from there
>   u can push and pull Shared pref Files

Comment: This Answer will be useful for debuging with shared pref

Comment: I got up to File explorer - But how will i find out shared_pref folder under it? I dont see the app names like you are seeing above?

Comment: there is Data folder -> there is again nested Data folder -> there is package name -> then there is shared pref Folder -> there u can find ur files

Answer (score 1):

Try this code of snippet.. It works perfect...

OnCreate Method code :

```
        pref = getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREF_SETTINGS, 0); 

        rg_numberOfQuestions = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
        rb_1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioOne);
        rb_1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);


        rb_2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioTwo);
        rb_2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

        rb_3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioThree);
        rb_3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);


        int selected_radio_button = pref.getInt("radio", 0);
        if(selected_radio_button!=0)
        {
            RadioButton  button = (RadioButton) findViewById(selected_radio_button);
            button.setChecked(true);
        }
```

And the listener code :

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if(isChecked)
    {
        Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putInt("radio", buttonView.getId());
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seem Initialization of `share-preference` is not correct. can you just try below code@

```
private void savePref(String key, int value) {
      pref = getSharedPreferences("ANYNAME",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putInt(key, value);      
        editor.commit();
    }
```